# Other fantastic creature in Twilight Saga

Tags: twilight

When Bella discovered that not only vampires but also werewolves exist, she said something like, *"what, now every legend and tale exists?"*. I also recall Edward was with her and responded with a smile.

I've seen the movies, and didn't see any other creatures apart from werewolves, vampires (wizard vampires really), and hybrids. Did I miss something ?

Comment: http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Moon

Comment: http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Shapeshifter

Comment: http://twilightsaga.wikia.com/wiki/Gifted_humans

Answer (score -1):

It's subtext. It's almost certain that, in the Twilight universe, there exists other beings and creatures. It is left, though, to the watchers imagination to wonder exactly what.

Witches could easily be worked into a future Twilight film.

Comment: I've downvoted since this seems like pure guesswork. On what are you basing this contention that "it's almost certain"?

Comment: It would seem to be implausible but certainly possible that the only supernatural beings in the world are vampires and werewolves.  Only Stephenie Meyer can make that determination though.  I would very much like to see a new series of books by her set in the /Twilight/ universe, but with a wider cast of supernatural beings.

Comment: So two things: Bella, even as a human, had a gift (immunity to many of the vampire mental abilities). Second, the "children of the moon" (true werewolves, unlike the shape changers of Jacob's tribe). So it seems absolutely reasonable to presume that there are even more supernatural/preternatural humans or groups that just haven't been talked about yet.

Answer (score -1):

It is well-known that Jacob is actually a shape-shifter, not a werewolf. And real werewolves are called Children Of The Moon, and look a little different and are feral in their wolf forms. Vampires feared them and hunted them to near extinction.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This would be a better answer if you could add some quotes that establish that werewolves are a separate creature type from the shape-shifters.